# <img src=""> is generating different path after build in vuejs/webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I'm new in Vuejs. I'm working in a project where i have to show an image in Vue component. In my component i'm showing image like this:

`<img src="./../../images/back-arrow.png">`

Then after built is not showing. When i inspect to my code, its showing different address like this:

`<img src="/js/back-arrow.png?c4a414352d997e4618088074e1da917a">`

My folder structures are:

- assets

  - components

    - VueTemplate.vue    //this is where i'm showing my images
  - images

    - back-arrow.png
  - js    //npm run build location

I don't know why it's changing, can anyone help me out? TIA

My webpack config:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './admin/assets/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'admin/js'),
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filename: 'graphs-lite-admin.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'images/'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    //   sourceMap: true,
    //   compress: {
    //     warnings: false
    //   }
    // }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you created the project with vue-cli 3.0, you can remove it with filenameHashing option.

Create `vue.config.js` file on your project root, then write this.

```
module.exports = {
  filenameHashing: false
}
```

See this link: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing

Or if you are using webpack config file, remove `[hash]` from output.

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js'
}
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename

Answer (score -1):

I found a temporary solution. The problem was in webpack. I had to use a loader. I i used url-loader.

```
 {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',  //adding this line solved my problem
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
    }
  }
```

Comment: url-loader converted my image to base64, which i don't want. It is not accessing direct assets.